# Symfony2.3: Override crud layout?

Tags: symfony, twig, crud

I'm attempting to override the crud template by specifying the application's layout in the extends statement.  Instead of

```
{{ "{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}" }}
```

I tried

```
{{ "{% extends 'ManaClientBundle:Default:layout.html.twig' %}" }}
```

This, however, yields

> [Twig_Error_Syntax]
>   Unexpected token "name" of value "ManaClientBundle" ("end of print
>   statement" expected) in "cru     d/views/show.html.twig.twig" at line
>   2

Using:

```
{{ "{% extends "::layout.html.twig" %}" }}
```

This error occurs:

> [Twig_Error_Syntax]
>   Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("end of print statement"
>   expected) in "crud/views/     show.html.twig.twig" at line 2

What, if any, is the appropriate syntax to replace the layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% verbatim %}
     {% extends 'AcmeYourBundle:Default:layout.html.twig' %}
{% endverbatim %}
```

Further read the [escaping chapter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#escaping) of the documentation.

Please note that prior to twig `1.12` the tag was named `{% raw %}` ([reference](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html)).